# Is there a way to shorten use of an if statement in an assignment?

Tags: c#

for instance, if I have this code:

```
if (foo != default(foo))
{ 
  int foo2 = foo; 
}
```

is there a way to shorten this to only the assignment? in pseudocode, something like:
foo2 = if not default foo

Comment: Is there an `else` condition? It could be `int foo2 = foo != default(foo)? foo : 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with trying to shorten this is that `foo2` is only valid within the scope inside your if statement.  By moving this into one line, you'd always have to have `foo2` defined in the outer scope, and it would always need *some* value.

If that is acceptable, you could use [C#'s conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
int foo2 = foo != default(foo) ? foo : default(int);
```

Note that you need something for when `foo == default(foo)`, as well, which becomes the final portion.  With an int value, I would probably use `: 0;` at the end, but since you're checking against `default(foo)`, I'm assuming your "real use case" is probably not an `Int32` value...

---

Edit:

> The (int) was an afterthought, in what I was actually trying I already had foo2 assigned so this is exactly what I was looking for.

Given this comment, you could do:

```
foo2 = foo != default(foo) ? foo : foo2;
```

This would effectively reassign `foo2` if `foo` doesn't have it's default value, and leave it alone (assign it to itself) if it does.

That being said, I personally prefer something similar to your original:

```
// Assumes foo2 is already defined, based on your comment
if (foo != default(foo))
    foo2 = foo;
```

This is, in my opinion, far more clear in terms of your intent, and does avoid the extra assignment to yourself that you're getting with a conditional operator.

Comment: Ah, okay. The (int) was an afterthought, in what I was actually trying I already had foo2 assigned so this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: `int foo2 = foo != default(foo) ? foo : default(int);` is exactly the same as `int foo2 = foo`, but without quite as much (pointless) overhead.

Comment: @Servy I know - but I'm assuming there was some other rationale, which was why I explained explicitly that "something" needs to go into the last statement.

Comment: @Servy I agree that the example, as is, is useless - the OP's sample code is meaningless, as `foo2` is declared in its own scope, so effectively becomes a null op there ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// either
int foo2 = (foo != default(foo)) ? foo : default(int);
// or
int? foo2 = (foo != default(foo)) ? foo : null;
```

Comment: The whole point of the code in the OP is that the variable never exists in the first place if `foo` is the default value, not that you want to set it to the default value.  Your code is identical to just saying `foo2 = foo`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, OP doesn't state anywhere that `foo2` must not exist outside the `if`-block.

Comment: If you're just going to move it outside the `if` block then, as I said before, why wouldn't you just use `int foo2 = foo`?  It does exactly the same thing, but without the ponitless overhead.  Since the OP didn't do that, I would assume it's important that `foo2` not exist at all when `foo` is the default value.  He asked for a way to simplify what the provided code does.  Your code doesn't do the same thing, so being shorter isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to simplify that any more than you have.  If you were just setting the value of `foo2` rather than declaring it (and in a scope block as well) then you could conceivably refactor it into a method for a tiny gain.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
foo2 = foo != default(foo) ? foo : foo2;
```

Comment: that would be identical to just saying `foo2 = foo`, and it's not the same as what the OP does.